# C# panel background image splitting on scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I'm working on a winforms application using C#. I have a form with background image, and a panel on that with transparent background. Some data and controls will be dynamically created on this panel.

This panel has a scroll bar, when I scrolls that background image is splitting and page and data is looking very odd.

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue? All I need that background image should not split on scrolling of the panel...

Thanks in Advance.
Suhasini

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation on winforms. Check out [this post](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=312553) for an explanation.